# How to  remove all \n \r \t in an XmlDocument?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmldocument

Is it possible to remove \n, \r, \t, and other non-visible characters such as whitespace in XmlDocument?

I tried `PreserveWhiteSpace = False` and `IgnoreWhiteSpace = True` for `XmlReaderSettings`, but those didn't work.

Comment: Do you mean between elements or in text nodes? And can you explain _why_ you need to do this, as whitespace is not significant in XML?

Comment: Both.  The reason I need to do this is because the first child of the soap body is being read as \n.

Comment: Will you need to do this more than once?

Comment: yes, it is in multiple places in the document

Comment: How do they get there in the first place?  Is it if I copy from the xml from a Microsoft Word document.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, 'will you need to do this for more than one file?'

Comment: Well, they normally won't be coming from Files, but yes, it is more than one file.

Comment: Bummer, I would have said "just throw it in Notepad++, and use it's find and replace functionality. You could try processing the file as a string, and just use yourfile.Replace(vbCrLf, "").Replace(vbTab, ""), etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using XSLT, but make sure that the XSL template will not be [introducing some other whitespace back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468984/xslt-remove-whitespace-from-template).